# How to add more peers and orderers to test network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, peer

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and I'm trying to use the test-network template.

I'm trying to extend the test-network by adding new peers and orderers with the Fabric CAs.

Does anyone know how to do that or have some kind of tutorial? I already saw examples online but they were with the cryptogen tool.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi @catsdev! You may use those tutorials that you have found. Instead of generating the crypto material with the cryptogen tool, you will generate the crypto material for your new peers using your CA. But the, the following steps are the ones that are explained at the following manual: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/channel_update_tutorial.html#bring-up-org3-components

Answer (score 0):

To add new organizational peer into a running network you can follow their tutorial on official doc. It uses Fabric CA and you have to use "-ca" flag. By maintaining almost similar process, you can add new orderer organization too.

Tutorial link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/channel_update_tutorial.html#

Code repository: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/test-network/addOrg3

If you want to develop your network with more peers & orderers, we need clear understanding about Fabric CA.

Fabric Ca link: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/deployguide/ca-deploy.html#

1st you have to write docker-compose-ca.yaml file. you can follow the following link:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/docker/docker-compose-ca.yaml

2nd you have to create fabric-ca-server configuration yaml file. You can follow the following link:https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1

3rd you have to use fabric-ca-client to register and enroll peers and orderers. You can follow the following link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/registerEnroll.sh

To learn about fabric ca, you can follow the following tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJTdJt6N6Ow&list=PLSBNVhWU6KjW4qo1RlmR7cvvV8XIILub6

You can find your answer on lecture 41,42,43,44,45.

Comment: The docker-compose part is already done. The thing is I want to build a network with more than one peers since the beginig so I have to change the files inside the directory organizations, like the ccp-generate.sh ccp-template.json, ccp-template.yaml and also the registerEnroll.sh but I don't know how to do that in the correct way.